# How to print string diagonally from right to left?

Tags: printing

How can I print something diagonally , for example stars * , but diagonally from right to left? I know for the normal diagonal left-to right we just use a for loop with variable "i" in another for loop with variable "j" and put if function to print the string if i=j. but how to do it opposite?

Comment: You would subtract instead of add, which means you have to start at the width and height of the available page space.

Comment: what do you mean by page space? thank you for your answer

Comment: The printable area minus the margins.

Comment: I am still having trouble with it. Could you help me out with it, for example, if I had a rectangle that is 8x16 big, how would I set up those for loops for the opposite diagonal in it?

Comment: You would have to edit your question to include the code you are using.  You haven't even specified what language you are using, so update the tag, too.

Comment: I am using C. Thank you so much for your answers, I've managed to do it finally by using reversed for loop with decrement